# Confirm that file has been downloaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there a way to confirm that a user has downloaded a file? (As opposed to having refused the download, or cancelling it in the middle?) Preferably in c# codebehind.

When using: `Response.Write(...);` .

Comment: context.Response.Flush();
context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Comment: @AntoKing That's like `Response.End();` . It will just send the file (and stop execution of the page.)

Comment: But Response.End Will throw an exception i hope

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Response.IsClientConnected` to check if still client is connected.

From MSDN

> This property enables you greater control over circumstances where the
>   client may have reset the connection to the server. For example, if a
>   long period of time has elapsed between when a client request was made
>   and when the server responded, it may be beneficial to make sure the
>   client is still connected before continuing to process the script.

After write to response using `Response.Write`, execute this to check if client is connected, if that is true means file is written to response/ downloaded.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525453(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, the download only begins after the `Response.End();`. Which also stops execution of the page.

Comment: I was thinking for this example - http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/asynchronously-streaming-video-with-asp-net-web-api/, note: nothing to do with video thing, just an idea - async download file ( via writing content async.)